# I need to increase the quantity on cart screen and also decrease the quantity also with a + and - icons

Tags: flutter, dart

```
    void addToCart(ProductModel product) {
            if (cartItems.contains(product)) {
              int index = cartItems.indexOf(product);
              cartItems.remove(product);
              product.quantity += 1;*/Error on this line/*
              cartItems.insert(index, product);
            } else {
              if (product.quantity == 0) {
                product.quantity += 1;*/Error on this line/*
              }
              cartItems.add(product);
            }
          }
   void decreaseQuantity(ProductModel product) {
    if (cartItems.contains(product)) {
      int index = cartItems.indexOf(product);
      cartItems.remove(product);
      if (product.quantity > 1) {
        product.quantity -= 1*/Erroro on here/*;
        cartItems.insert(index, product);
      }
    }
  }
```

**Error**

> The method '+' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver
> can be 'null'. Try making the call conditional (using '?.') or adding
> a null check to the target ('!').

Comment: void decreaseQuantity(ProductModel product) {
    if (cartItems.contains(product)) {
      int index = cartItems.indexOf(product);
      cartItems.remove(product);
      if (product.quantity > 1) {
        product.quantity -= 1; // Eroor in here//
        cartItems.insert(index, product);
      }
    }
  }

Comment: From the error message, it seems possible that quantity field may be null. Can you post the ProductModel class? Also please don't post comments that should be edits to the question.

Comment: show the code related to your ProductModel (mainly it's constructor)

Answer (score 0):

use

```
product.quantity++;
```

hope this helpts

Answer (score 0):

3 solutions are available to you:

- Add `!`

  product.quantity! += 1;
- Initialize the quantity by `0` in the ProductModel
- Change the type of the quantity by `dynamic`

One of them can help